# Embed Website using iframe but iframe doesn't scroll on IOS

Tags: html, css, iframe, scroll

I am tring to embed a website into another website using iframe witch works greet on everything but 
on my ipad, the scrolling seem to be lagging or just not working. Any help smoothing out the scroll action and changing the color of the scrolls would be awesome!

Here is the code iam using

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="scroller" style="height: 800px; width: 600; overflow: auto;">
<iframe height="100%" id="iframe" scrolling="auto" width="100%" id="iframe"     src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zIqCVUo27R73tiJZQLkVCxDt3Kg7kiXqLyzRBLT7_AQ/edit#gid=512    365425" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function () {
var startY = 0;
var startX = 0;
var b = document.body;
b.addEventListener('touchstart', function (event) {
parent.window.scrollTo(0, 1);
startY = event.targetTouches[0].pageX;
startX = event.targetTouches[0].pageY;
});
b.addEventListener('touchmove', function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
var posy = event.targetTouches[0].pageY;
var h = parent.document.getElementById("scroller");
var sty = h.scrollTop;
var posx = event.targetTouches[0].pageX;
var stx = h.scrollLeft;
h.scrollTop = sty - (posy - startY);
h.scrollLeft = stx - (posx - startX);
startY = posy;
startX = posx;
});
}, 10000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the [link](http://hyperlethal.shivtr.com/pages/BAND) so you can see for yourself if you like.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Had some progress but still not working how i would like

Comment: At first I was embedding another website but also using this code to embed some google docs with the same none scrolling issues on Ipads